# Wordpress multisite haml templates

Tags: plugins, multisite, templates

I'm building a very large Wordpress multisite at the moment and while I sort out the project at a top level I want to know if it's possible to use haml or phamlp for my templates instead of php.

I have seen two plugins for Wordpress but neither of them seem to work with a multi-site.

My question is, how would I write a VERY basic plugin to read the templates and output them in place of the usual ones?

I want to use haml because it's much cleaner than large html/php templates and I just want to parse header.haml instead of header.php if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter `template_include` and use your own templates:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
    return $path_to_template;
});
```

The `$path_to_template` should point to file that renders your templates.

Comment: Thanks for this, does this tell me which template file I need to load? Sorry I've not done anything like this with Wordpress before. Such as header.php would load header.haml and serve raw content or would I have to compile a file to serve?

Comment: You would have to compile that before you send it. This filter asks only for the main files (`single.php`, `archive.php`), you don’t have to use a `header.php`. Be aware: if you never call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`, many plugins will not work.

Comment: Thanks, it's okay. For my sanity I've ditched the idea for now. Your answer was on the right track but I don't have the time to fully investigate it. Thanks anyway.